# Laravel pass id to my sql on button click from view

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to `activate` or `deactivate` the products for a form  using  `$product->status`

The  active button shows if `$product->status` is 0 and
The  deactive button shows if `$product->status` is 1

I want to toggle the value of  `$product->status`  in the mysql database every time I click on the button

```
 <form action="{{route('invetory.create')}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicTable">
    <tr>
      <th>item</th>
      <th>tax</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    @forelse($products as $product)
    <input type="text" name="item" value="{{$product->id}}
    class="form-control" hidden />
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="item" value="{{$product->item}}
      class="form-control" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="tax" value="{{$product->tax}}
      class="form-control" />
    </td>

   @if($product->status =='0')
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-success remove-tr active_btn">active</button>
    </td>
  @else
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr deactive_btn">Deactive</button>
    </td>
  @endif
  </table>
</form>
```

here i have given the route i have used
web.php

```
Route::post('/update', 'App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController@update')>name('invetory.update');
```

here i have added the controler i have used
InventoryController.php

```
public function update(Request $REQUEST){
  dd($REQUEST->all());
  
       Inventory::update( $REQUEST->invetory as $key => $value);
 
    return redirect()->action([InventoryController::class, 'index']);
}
```

i am geting 500 error when i click button

Comment: Can you please ensure `APP_DEBUG` is `true` in your `.env` file and give details about you 500 error so we can know what the error is ?

Comment: Your Laravel log will tell you why you are getting a 500 error. My guess is you have mixed up your routes - the form targets `invetory.create` (even though it is not a form for creating a record), but the route you show is named `invetory.update`.  Also, in your controller method, you're referencing `$REQUEST->invetory` but there is nothing in the form named `invetory` (which seems to be a typo as well).

Comment: What error do you see in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using POST request which will refresh the page each time you toggle a product or you can use AJAX to do the change asynchronously. Using Javascript and AJAX would be the preferred way so you don't lose selected filters, pagination etc.

You don't need external packages to implement that, you can use JavaScript's fetch method. Also, instead of having 2 separate functions and routes, I would suggest having one route that would toggle the product's status, i.e. if it is active, make it inactive and vice versa. That method by definition should be a POST request, by I prefer doing GET requests for this in order to avoid CSRF protection and use middleware to protect the request.

Here is the complete code.

1. Register a web route that toggles the state inside `web.php`

```
Route::get('projects/toggle', [ProjectController::class, 'toggle'])->name('projects.toggle');
```

2. Implement the `toggle` method in `ProjectController.php`

```
public function toggle(Request $request) {
    $project = Project::find($request->project_id);

    $project->status = !$project->status;

    $project->save();

    return response()->json(['status' => (int) $project->status]);
}
```

*Notice that I am returning a json response which includes the new project status. We will use this in the JavaScript code to dinamically update the column where the status is shown.*

3. Finally, in the blade file, when iterating through the projects, the button click calls a function that will do the AJAX request. Notice that I am also adding an `id` attribute to the columns that contains the status so I can access it dinamically in order to update it.

```
 @foreach($projects as $project)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$project->title}}</td>
        <td id="project-status-{{$project->id}}">{{$project->status}}</td>
        <td><button onClick="toggleStatus('{{$project->id}}')">Toggle</button></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

In this same file, we add the following JavaScript code. It accepts project_id as parameter which is passed from the button click, makes the ajax request to backend which updates the status and then updates the appropriate DOM element to show the new status.

```
function toggleStatus(project_id) {
    fetch("{{ route('projects.toggle') }}?project_id=" + project_id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            document.querySelector("#project-status-" + project_id).innerHTML = response.status;
     })
}
```

As I mentioned, you can use multiple options in the JavaScript part. Instead of calling a function you can register an event listener to each button, but this approach with function call is a bit quicker. Also, I am passing the project_id as `GET` parameter, you can define the route to contain it as route parameter, but then you'll need to do some string replacements in order to do in dinamically in JavaScript. All in all, the proposed is a good solution that will serve your purpose.

p.s. For stuff like this, [LiveWire](https://laravel-livewire.com/) is a perfect fit.

Comment: @meon did you get it right?

Answer (score 1):

Using `dd` (e.g. in your controller) will throw a 500 error. It literally stands for "dump and die".

Answer (score 1):

check you routes in form use`{{route('invetory.create')}}` 
and in routes you given `inventory.update`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function Stauts(Request $request)
{
    $product= Product::findOrFail($request->id);
    $product->active == 1 ? $product->active = 0 : $product->active = 1 ;
    $product->update();
    return response()->json(['status' => true,'msg' =>  'Staut updated']);
}
```

in blade use ajax

```
 <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.status-product', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var product_id = $(this).data('id');
        var url ="{{ route('product.status') }}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
             data: {
             '_token': "{{csrf_token()}}",
              'id': product_id 
             },
          success: function (data) {
               if (data.status == true) {
                  $('#deactive_ajax').show();}
              }
       })
    })
</script>

   Route::post('product/stauts/', [productController::class,'Stauts'])->name('product.Stauts');
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**
Using a form with tables is not ideal and some browsers already made changes to prevent that.

**Secondly**
The best way is as **DCodeMania** said, the ajax request is the best way to solve this, I'll just modify his answer a bit and use Patch instead of PUT, so it'll look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.active_btn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ route("products.update") }}',
      method: 'PATCH',
      data: {
        id: id,
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
```

and you'll only be needing one button so no need to make the check for $product->status he added, just a single button for the toggle will make your code cleaner.

As for using **PATCH** instead of **PUT**, because you're only updating one single column and not the whole thing getting updated, and no need for the status parameter, you'll just reverse what's inside the database

```
$product = Product::find($request->id);
Product::where('id', $product->id)->update([
 'status' => $product->status ? 0 : 1,
]);
```

You'll also need one button with different text based on status
like this

```
<td>
      <button type="button" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-success remove-tr active_btn">{{ $product->status == 1 ? 'deactivate' : 'activate' }}</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way and it works for me

First in view does this

```
<td>
   @if ($producto->estado == '1')
       <a href="{{ url('/status-update-producto', $producto->id) }}"
            class="btn btn-success" id="btn_estado">Activo</a>
   @else
       <a href="{{ url('/status-update-producto', $producto->id) }}"
            class="btn btn-danger" id='btn_estado'>Inactivo</a>
   @endif
</td>
```

Controller

```
  function updateStatusProducto($id)
  {
    //get producto status with the help of producto ID
    $producto = DB::table('productos')
      ->select('estado')
      ->where('id', '=', $id,)
      ->first();

    //Check producto status
    if ($producto->estado == '1') {
      $estado = '0';
    } else {
      $estado = '1';
    }

    //update producto status
    $values = array('estado' => $estado);
    DB::table('productos')->where('id', $id)->update($values);

    return redirect()->route('productos.index');
  }
```

Route

```
Route::get('/status-update-producto/{id}', [ProductoController::class, 'updateStatusProducto']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some data attributes to your buttons, and use them in js to send an ajax request

```xml
@if ($product->status =='0')
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success toggle-tr" data-product="{{ $product->id }}" data-status="{{ $product->status }}">active</button>
  </td>
@else
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger toggle-tr" data-product="{{ $product->id }}" data-status="{{ $product->status }}">Deactive</button>
  </td>
@endif
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-tr').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const product = e.target.dataset.product;
  const status = e.target.dataset.status == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  // send ajax or fetch request passing in product_id. If we're going with a RESTful approach,
  axiox.patch(`/products/${product}`, { status })
    .then(res => { ... })
    .catch(err => { ...});  
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ajax here:

Pass product id in `data-id` attribute

```
@if($product->status =='0')
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-success remove-tr active_btn">active</button>
    </td>
  @else
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr deactive_btn">Deactive</button>
    </td>
  @endif
```

then use ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.active_btn', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let id = $(this).data('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("products.update") }}',
        method: 'PUT',
        data: {
          id: id,
          status: 1,
          _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.deactive_btn', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let id = $(this).data('id');
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("products.update") }}',
        method: 'PUT',
        data: {
          id: id,
          status: 0,
          _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    });
```

Now you can handle the request in the controller.

Comment: how can i use ajax in larvel can i write at the end of my blade file using script?

Comment: If you are using layout then set `@yield('scripts')` just before the closing body tag but also make sure to include jquery file above this yield, then you can use `@section('scripts') <script>jquery_code </script> @endsection` in your blade view file which is extending the layout.

Comment: can u pls provide the controler code also

Comment: can u pls provide the routes i must be using @DCode mania